# loop within an execution command

Tags: shell, loops

I would like to execute 120 models a shell script for 100 years. i.e.

```
start=1900; end=2000
using model1,model2, model3 and so on until 120 models
```

I can execute them manually with following command: (lets say 3 models)

```
exec "${script_dir}myscript $start $end $model1 $model2 $model3"
```

How can I use a loop to extend the above command something like

```
exec "${script_dir}myscript $start $end $model1 $model2 $model3 $model4 ..... $model120"
```

Comment: Please specify how the 120 models should be distributed over 100 years.

Comment: Are you really looking for a POSIX-compliant solution, as your tags suggest, or is `bash` acceptable (which would simplify the answer)?

Comment: I am looking something which will be look like exec `${script_dir}myscript $start $end $model1 $model2 $model3 and so on until $model120` Can you please suggest

Answer (score 3):

```
start=1900
end=2000
command="\${script_dir}myscript \$start \$end"
i=1

while [ $i -le 120 ]
do
    command="$command \$model$i"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done

exec $command
```

This script will simply do a for loop from 1 to 120 and concatenate all the models to your command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am looking something which will be look like `exec "${script_dir}myscript $start $end $model1 $model2 $model3 and so on until $model120` Can you please suggest

Comment: Do you need the variable values or just this exact text?

Comment: I need the exact text. Because this command will provide the path of model to myscript.

Comment: I edited the script by escaping the $ signs in the command. This way you'll get the exact text. Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, because this will literraly try to execute the command ${script_dir}myscript which will probably result in "not found".